# How can I copy a comment from a PDF opened with Google Chrome's built-in PDF file viewer?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, copy, comments

I opened with Google Chrome's built-in PDF file viewer. The PDF contains a comment:

[image]

How can I copy the text of a comment from a PDF opened with Google Chrome's built-in PDF file viewer?

Comment: I think you will need an extension...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to copy the text of a comment from a PDF opened with Google Chrome's built-in PDF file viewer.  [Saaransh Garg](https://superuser.com/users/1219498/saaransh-garg) [commented](https://superuser.com/questions/1705757/how-can-i-copy-a-comment-from-a-pdf-opened-with-google-chromes-built-in-pdf-fil#comment2627517_1705757) it may be possible with an extension.